# istream and get line

Tags: c++, istream

So I'm trying to create a function that validates a file but I can't figure out why all my variable are empty after I `getline(p_is, team);`

The file contains on line 1 the name of a hockey after that a list of first name and last name like this :

```
TeamName
FirstName1
LastName1
FirstName2
LastName2
FirstName3
LastName3
```

This is what I do :

In my main :

```
ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
bool test = util::validateFile(myfile);
```

and this is my function(basic version) :

```
bool validateFile(std::istream& p_is)
{
string team = "";
string firstname = "";
string lastname = "";

getline(p_is, team);

while (!p_is.eof()){

    getline(p_is, firstname);
    if (firstname.empty())
    {return false;}

    getline(p_is, lastname);
    if (lastname.empty())
    {return false;}
    }

if (team.empty())
    {return false;}
    else
    {return true;}
```

When I debug i it returns false because team is empty...
In my main I can print to console the stream and it's ok and I also tried to redo my .txt incase it was corrupted

any idea ?

EDIT : I add p_is.peek(); and now it goes into the while loop but still empty is my getline ok ?

Answer (score 0):

The first time `firstname` is empty (after reading `team` and alternating `firstname` and `lastname`), the function `validateFile` returns `false`. This way, you can fix the problems:

```
bool validateFile(std::istream& p_is) {
  string team, firstname, lastname;

  getline(p_is, team);
  while( p_is ) {
    if( !getline(p_is, firstname) )
      return !team.empty();
    if( firstname.empty() )
      return false;
    if( !getline(p_is, lastname) )
      return !team.empty(); // this could be false;
    if( lastname.empty() )
      return false;
  }

  return !team.empty();
}
```